# Is the Gamma function defined for complex numbers like so?

Tags: complex-numbers, factorial, gamma-function

I know $\Gamma (x)$ can be defined as...

$$\Gamma (x) = (x-1)!$$

And as...

$$\Gamma (x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{x-1} e^{-u} \space du$$

But assuming we had a *Complex variable* $z$ and had the following...

$$(z-1)!$$

Would it be correct for me to say...

$$\Gamma (z) = (z-1)!$$

Or is that only defined for *Natural values*?

Comment: you can't write $z!$ if $z \not \in \mathbb{N}$ but you have $\Gamma(z+n) = \Gamma(z) \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (z+k)$ and the notation $\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(z+1+n)}{\Gamma(z+1) \Gamma(n+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(z+1+n)}{\Gamma(z+1) n!} = {n+z \choose n}$ see [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: and a great exercice is proving that your integral converges only for $Re(x) \ge 0, x \ne 0$, and that $\Gamma(1) = 1,\ \Gamma(\epsilon) \sim 1/\epsilon, \ \Gamma(-1+\epsilon) \sim -1/\epsilon, \ldots$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Gamma(z)$ is a function of a complex variable $z$ so that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for $n = 1,2,...$, the positive integers.  Just writing $\Gamma(z) = (z-1)!$ does not give a definition for $\Gamma(z)$.  However, sometimes the notation $z!$ is used to denote the value of $\Gamma(z+1)$.  If you *define* the symbol $z!$ to mean $\Gamma(z+1)$ then the statement $\Gamma(z) = (z-1)!$ is true.  You can use the symbol $!$ this way if you want, but you should probably clarify your definitions beforehand.

Comment: This is right.  I'll add that this is a lot like saying $\zeta(0) = 1 + 1 + 1 + \dots = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DanBrumleve - Ahh I see...it's like, $\zeta(-1) = {-1\over 12}$ ... so the integral representation of the Gamma function is like an '*Analytically Continued*' version of $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)! \space x \in \mathbb{N}$, where the domain is extended to all real and complex values.

Comment: Yes, kind of, the $\Gamma$ function is not an analytic continuation of factorial since factorial is only defined on integers, but both are cases where it makes sense to use the same notation for a particular extension of the domain.

Comment: Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha use the same convention: http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%21&x=0&y=0